# Universal-Aanalytics: Visitor.event() call is failing with label values

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-cloud-functions, universal-analytics

I am using [universal-analytics](https://github.com/peaksandpies/universal-analytics) for Google Analytics, but the `visitor.event()` call with label value as a string is not working.

As per the below document, it says the label value should be non-negative, does it mean it only accepts Integers or String as well?
https://github.com/peaksandpies/universal-analytics/blob/master/AcceptableParams.md

**FYI:**

`visitor.event(category, action, label).send();` // Working and events are reported.

Example: {"category":"APISvc","action":"URLStats","label":"Called"}

`visitor.event(category, action, label, labelValue).send();` // NOT Working.

Example: {"category":"APISvc","action":"URLStats","label":"Success","labelValue":"2S"}

**Context**: Using this in Cloud Functions (NodeJS) on Google Firebase.

Appreciating your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **value** component, for a Google Analytics event, if it is defined it must be an **integer** (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en).

Example:

```
{"category":"APISvc","action":"URLStats","label":"Success","labelValue":2}
```

Comment: Thank for the clarification.  But, I am not sure why they enforced it for only Integer values, and not being able to track other valuable string values.  The previous versions ga.js, analytics.js, etc are still supporting multiple value types.

Comment: Event value is a metric so it cannot be a string; ga.js and analytics.js definitely doesn't support strings for event value.